# Diffusion coefficient of Yperine (sulfur mustard) in water

Tags: diffusion

I'm currently working on a project and I need the diffusion coefficients of Yperine in water.
I've searched online and I haven't found anything.
If any of you have information about this (or diffusion coefficients of similar gases) that'd be really helpful !

Comment: The name "Yperine" doesn't seem to be common at all. The other name "sulfur mustard" turns up Yperite, not Yperine, but its solubility in water is negligible...

Comment: @probably_someone: correct (Yperite): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustard_gas. Forget finding $D$ values for that. Try maybe for 1,5 dichloropentane (similar structure).

Comment: is this, perhaps, a better question for Chemistry.SE?

Comment: After having just looked at several different tables giving a couple hundred diffusion coefficients of various gases in water, it seems that all of them are within an order of magnitude of $10^{-5}$ cm$^2$/s. Depending on your project's precision, this may be all you need.